# java: overridden compareTo() not recognized in static method

Tags: java, overriding, compareto

I wrote a class called Member that implements Comparable.
I have overridden the compareTo method
I wrote another class called BinarySearch that contains one static method called binarySearch
in that method i have:

```
    public class BinarySearch {


    private BinarySearch(){
    }

    public static int binarySearch(List<Member> list, Member member){
       int low = 0;                  
       int high = list.size();     
       int middle;                  

    while ( low <= high ) 
    {
      middle = ( low + high ) / 2;
      if ( member.equals(list.get(middle)))  
         return middle;
      else if ( member.compareTo(list.get(middle)) < 0)
         high = middle - 1;  
      else
         low = middle + 1;   
   }

   return -1; 
}
```

}

The line:

```
    member.compareTo(list.get(middle))
```

gives an error saying: cannot find method compareTo(object).
Yet the compiler can find the method in my other classes.
All other methods of my Member class are visible in the binarySearch method as well.

the Member class:

```
    public class Member implements Comparable<Member>{
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private int level;

    public Member(){
        this("","","","",-1);
    }

    public Member(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber,      int level){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.level = level;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public Member setFirstName(String firstName) {
    return new Member(firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.phoneNumber, this.level);
}

public Member setLastName(String lastName) {
    return new Member(this.firstName, lastName, this.email, this.phoneNumber, this.level);
}

public Member setEmail(String email) {
    return new Member(this.firstName, this.lastName, email, this.phoneNumber, this.level);
}

public Member setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    return new Member(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, phoneNumber, this.level);
}

public Member setLevel(int level) {
    return new Member(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.phoneNumber, level);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Member other = (Member) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.lastName, other.lastName)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.phoneNumber, other.phoneNumber)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Member{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + 
            ", email=" + email + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + ", level=" + 
            level + '}';
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Member t) {
    if (equals(t)){
        return 0;
    }
    if (lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(t.lastName) == -1){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You are using a raw type. I assumed that you define your `compareTo` method as `public int compareTo(Member o)`.

Comment: Ah @ZouZou! i had to delete my comment. yours is the likelier suspect.

Comment: its actually this: public int compareTo(Object t)

Comment: @user3011690 Then your code should work (although you'll have warnings).

Comment: thats what i thought! i figured netbeans got flustered or something so i restarted it...nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your List doesn't have a type parameter, so everything you `get` from it defaults to being treated as an `Object`, while judging by your error message your `compareTo` only accepts comparison with other `Member` objects. You can fix this by changing the type of the list from `List` to `List<Member>` - or alternatively (but kludgier) rework your `compareTo` to work with `Object` or use type casting.

Comment: i edited my post with my compareTo method. I tried changing the parameter to List<Member>...same problem except now the error is: cannot find method compareTo(Member)

Comment: @user3011690, is the `Comparable` interface implemented correctly? You need to have `Comparable<Member>` if you want `compareTo(Member m)`, or just `Comparable` if you want `compareTo(Object o)`.

Comment: ok i just changed my Member class to implement Comparable<Member>, and my compareTo method parameter to public int compareTo(Member t) then changed the binarySearch method signature to public static int binarySearch(List<Member> list, Member member) and am getting an error that says Cannot find method compareTo(Member)

Comment: @user3011690, in that case it should work. Bug in Java is never impossible, but since a bug in your code is far more probable I'm going to ask for more code to sort this out. Can we see the entire Member class?

Comment: another weird thing! i added the line Member copy = new Member(member); to my binarySearch method and it compiled even though, as you can see my Member class has no Member(Member other) constructor